# How do I save an array into session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I want to save an array in codeigniters' session helper but I keep getting

I want to save an array of arrays in a new session variable so that I can view that session in another controller if I need it or in another view.

my session is autoloaded in my config file.

this piece of code is in my view file.
$arr = array();

```
foreach($value->result as $val){}
    if($val->somethinghappenedtrue){
        $arr[] = array('data' => $thethingthathappened);
    }
}
// since my session is autoloaded I don't need to initialize
//session if I'm not wrong $this->load->session etc...
$this->session->new_session_name($arr);
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Session::new_session_name()

Comment: Did you load the session library?
$this->load->library('session');

Comment: is this CI 3.x - you could try the documentation, http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data  In any case your error is from calling a method that dosn't exist in CI_Session.  Because of some other integration that I use ( for membership logins ) with my CI sites I don't use CI for sessions....

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say a particular user logs into your site. Once authenticated, you could add their username and e-mail address to the session, making that data globally available to you without having to run a database query when you need it.

You can simply assign data to the $_SESSION array, as with any other variable. Or as a property of $this->session.

Alternatively, the old method of assigning it as “userdata” is also available. That however passing an array containing your new data to the set_userdata() method:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

> Your code should be

```
foreach($value->result as $val){}
    if($val->somethinghappenedtrue){
        $arr[] = array('data' => $thethingthathappened);
    }
}
// since my session is autoloaded I don't need to initialize
//session if I'm not wrong $this->load->session etc...
$this->session->set_userdata($arr);
```

If you want to add userdata one value at a time, set_userdata() also supports this syntax:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

If you want to verify that a session value exists, simply check with isset():

// returns FALSE if the 'some_name' item doesn't exist or is NULL,
// TRUE otherwise:

```
isset($_SESSION['some_name'])
```

Comment: the thing is that userdata already has data in it and I want to use a whole other variable other than the ones given. That is why I put `$this->session->new_session_name($arr);` with new_session_name as a whole new session variable. Can this not be done? Wont I alter the data that is in userdata if I add other unrelated things to it?

Comment: new_session_name() method doesnt exist in session refer ci doc https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html or https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html